# Kali Linux halts the CPU randomly

Tags: kali-linux, aircrack-ng, halts

I'm using Kali Linux 2.0 on a VMware VM. It halts the CPU, producing this [error](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2000542).

```
The CPU has been disabled by the guest operating system. Power off or reset the virtual machine.
```

I haven't been able to determine exactly when this happens, but I'm always running these three commands:

- [airodump-ng](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=airodump-ng)
- [aireplay-ng](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=aireplay-ng)
- [aircrack-ng](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=aircrack-ng)

I haven't found anything that helped me online. Do you have any ideas about how to find out what is happening and fix it?

Answer (score -1):

Kernel panic is a result of your CPU not liking what's going on. I suggest that you follow [this advice from Alexandre Kraft](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/246067#38) regarding x86 virtualization.

I'm guessing it is aircrack-ng which is causing the problem. Dictionary attacks (which is what I'm assuming you are doing) use a lot of CPU.